# install4j finish screen banner is not there after generation of installer

Tags: install4j

I have customized finish screen with banner image and have added multi-line label and 3 check boxes on that screen. In preview, everything seems fine. But after running the generated installer, banner is not there on the finish screen.
I tried using both default finish screen and empty form with banner.
Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Any error message in the .install4j/installation.log file? What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: @IngoKegel installation.log is saying "i4j_extf_5_0_6ibwfr.png" this file doesn't exist. I am using install4j version 7.0.2

Comment: Please try with 7.0.6, there were some style-related bugs that were fixed.

Comment: I have tried using 7.0.6, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com and send a sample project where the issue can be reproduced.